# Jmeter run stress test with formula

Tags: testing, jmeter

How can I run a Jmeter stress test with formula like 5 request per second on start and on each next second add plus 20 request per second?

For example, that I mean:
1s 5rps, 
2s 25rps, 
3s 45rps, 
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`request per second` is an outcome of what you have configured and server deployment etc. You really can't configure it. so, better focus on the number of threads (more the threads more the `request per second`), ramp-up, loop count, server resources, server configuration which effects `requests per second`.

In case you are looking for increasing load at regular intervals, try the JMeter plugins [Stepping Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/) or [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/), so you can launch the threads in the step pattern that you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try stepping thread groups.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using one of the following:

- [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) - see [Special Property Processing](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing)

  [image: Throughput Shaping Timer]
- [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/)

  [image: Concurrency Thread Group]

Both allow to define ramp-up basing on the desired concurrency, both are available via [JMeter Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/) project.

The fastest and the easiest way to install JMeter plugins and keep them updated is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)